# Techniques/patterns to achive Single Responsibility Principle in an extendable class hierarchy

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance, single-responsibility-principle

The Single Responsibility Principle says, for example, that an `Invoice` class should not contain the code to print itself. Printing should be separated out into a different class.

But suppose you have a hierarchy of `Invoice` classes in different layers of the software:

```
namespace CoreLayer {
    public class Invoice {
        public virtual void Print() {
            ...
        }
    }
}

namespace CustomizedLayer {
    public class LaborInvoice : Invoice {
        public override void Print() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class AccountInvoice : Invoice {
        public override void Print() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What techniques or design patterns can be used to separate out the printing reponsibility?

Ideas:

- A separate class with a great big `if` statement that tests for each subclass of `Invoice` and runs appropriate printing code. This seems wrong.
- Visitor pattern. The problem is that a visitor interface would need to exist in the Core layer with references to the classes in the Customized layer. I would like to be able to add new subclasses in the Customized layer with modifying the Core layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the [Acyclic Visitor (PDF)](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf).

Comment: Interesting read! The solution is presented in C++ using multiple inheritance and dynamic_cast. I happen to be using C#, but I think I can still use this by changing the abstract visitor classes into interfaces.

Comment: Look [here](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2012/12/the-acyclic-visitor-pattern.html) for a C# example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to subclass invoices? Do invoices differ in other things than printing? If no, there's no need to have different `Invoice` types, you just need different `InvoicePrinter` types passed to the `Invoice` instance:

```
namespace CoreLayer
{
    public class IInvoicePrinter
    {
        void Print(Invoice invoice);
    }

    public class Invoice
    {
    }
}

namespace CustomizedLayer
{
    public class LaborInvoicePrinter : IInvoicePrinter 
    {
        public void Print(Invoice invoice) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class AccountInvoicePrinter : IInvoicePrinter 
    {
        public void Print(Invoice invoice) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And you should have some kind of IoC to provide you with proper `InvoicePrinter` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bellow solution is useful for C#, it has no extera `if`, As I know, use of `visitor` pattern is not recommanded.

```
public class InvoicePrinterManager
{
     public void Print(AccountInvoice invoice)
     {
         AccountInvoicePrinter p1 = new AccountInvoicePrinter(invoice);
         p1.print();
     }

     public void Print(LaborInvoice invoice)
     {
         LaborInvoicePrinter p1 = new LaborInvoicePrinter(invoice);
         p1.print();
     }
}

public class InvoicePrinter<T> where T : Invoice, new()
{
    T instance;

    public InvoicePrinter(T invoice)
    {
        if (invoice != null)
        {
            this.instance = invoice;
        }
        else
            instance = new T();
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        /// Arrange objects as you want and print them.
    }
}

public class AccountInvoicePrinter : InvoicePrinter<AccountInvoice>
{
    public AccountInvoicePrinter(AccountInvoice invoice)
        : base(invoice)
    { 
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
       /// todo
    }
}

public class LaborInvoicePrinter : InvoicePrinter<LaborInvoice>
{
    public LaborInvoicePrinter(LaborInvoice invoice)
        : base(invoice)
    { 
    }
    public override void Print()
    {
        /// todo: use instance
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestPrint()
    {
        LaborInvoice li = new LaborInvoice();
        InvoicePrintManager printerManager = new InvoicePrintManager();
        printerManager.Print(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this helps to eliminate the if statement that checks for each subclass of Invoice. If I have an Invoice object that I want to print, how do I get an appropriate InvoicePrinter to print it?

Comment: When you KNOW where is a caller there is no need to extra if, but if you don't know the caller, yes you should have manager and i don't know how to prevent switch and reflection I'd think about it but i didn't find any good idea until now

Comment: @Joe Daley, I just updated my answer, there are some extra objects you can remove it. but i think sould be a better way.